# Ошибка при авторизации SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, авторизация

В чем может быть проблема?
Текст ошибки:

> Подключение к серверу успешно установлено, но затем произошла ошибка при входе. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - С обоих концов канала отсутствуют процессы.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Использую SQL Server Management Studio 2014. 
Пароль ввожу верно.

Comment: [Не оно](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430550/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ)?

Comment: Вы правильно вводите имя сервера? Попробуйте точку `.` вместо имени. Дефолтный выберется

Comment: Правильно, точно. Если подключаться с помощью авторизации Windows, то все хорошо проходит

Comment: @MaxU Все таки оно, Named Pipes было отключено  в настройках SQL Server в сетевых соединениях. Спасибо. Можете оформлять ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках SQL Server в пункте Сетевых соединение есть служба Named Pipes , ее надо включить

Comment: при подключении, можно просто выбрать `tcp` протокол, тогда и пайпы не надо будет включать, особенно, если вы ими не пользуетесь. Протокол можно выбрать так: `tcp:server,port`, например `tcp:127.0.0.1,1433`

Comment: @mega порт любой?

Comment: порт - тот, на котором у Вас висит mssql. 1433 - стандартный его порт.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема, решилось включением в свойствах сервера, на вкладки безопасность, проверка подлинности SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Если при этом в Application Event Log - Error 1032 для SQL Server:

sqlservr (xxxxx) Ошибка -1032 (0xfffffbf8) при открытии файла журнала C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Api.log.

или

sqlservr (ххххх) Не удалось открыть файл "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Api.log" только для чтения, системная ошибка 5 (0x00000005): "Отказано в доступе. ".  Операция открытия файла не будет выполнена, ошибка: -1032 (0xfffffbf8).

То надо дать права на доступ к папке C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\ пользователю, под которым запускается SQL Server.

Детали: https://support.microsoft.com/uk-ua/help/2811566/error-1032-messages-in-the-application-log-in-windows-server-2012